# I can't use ActionMessage from caliburn micro, how do I resolve it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

From what I read in the description of Caliburn Micro, this code should be compiled without problems. [Caliburn Description](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

```
<Button>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">           
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AbrirPDF">
            <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding CNPJ}"/>
        </cal:ActionMessage>            
    </i:EventTrigger>        
</i:Interaction.Triggers>   
</Button>
```

When trying this, I get the following error:

> ArgumentException: Cannot add instance of type 'ActionMessage' to a collection of type 'TriggerActionCollection'. Only items of type 'T' are allowed.

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Couldn’t you just use the shorthand syntax, i.e. `<Button cal:Message.Attach="AbrirPDF($dataContext.CNPJ)" />` which would call the designated method on a click?

Comment: This way it worked, I was able to pass the value to the parameter, but just using $ dataContext, I tried $ dataContext.CNPJ but the bind returned null ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the wrong namespace mappings. This should compile:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnMicroSample.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AbrirPDF">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding CNPJ}"/>
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The only installed NuGet package is [Caliburn.Micro 3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro/3.2.0).

Comment: very good, I was using version 4.0, when replacing with version 3.0 as in your example the code compiled without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues I had to add an extra xaml tag before calling `ActionMessage` my corresponding sample to get it to work was:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <cal:Action.Target>
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AbrirPDF">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding CNPJ}"/>
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </cal:Action.Target>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Then I was able to access the specified tag.

Answer (score 1):

For Caliburn.Micro v4 I found that changing the namespaces to the following fixed my issue and I did not have to add the extra `<cal:Action.Target>` tags

```
xmlns:cal="http://caliburnmicro.com"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Previously I had been using the following namespaces

```
xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/ for the explanation of the namespace change. As explained there you may need aditional changes in your project in order ro upgrade Caliburn.Micro from 3.x to 4.x.